# Convergence almost surely by definition

Tags: probability

I have to show convergence almost surely of the following sequence of random variables:
$X_n=\sqrt{n}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$. Honestly, I don't know how to show it by the definition of almost surely convergence.

Comment: $\sqrt{n}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1/n]}$ is a step function. Can you say something about where it converges and where it does not? To show almost sure convergence, you just need to show that the set where it does not converge has measure $0$.

Answer (score 4):

If $x>0$ then $|f_n(x)|=0 <\epsilon$ whenever $x> \frac 1n$ or $n >\frac  1x$. This proves that $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x \neq 0$. The set of points $x$ where $f_n(x)$ does not tend to $0$ coincides with $\{0\}$ which has measure $0$.