# $\sqrt{n} \mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ converges simply almost everywhere to $0$.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, almost-everywhere

I’m currently reading a book about Fourier series and I stumbled about a statement that won’t leave me alone (It’s not in relation with a Fourier series though). The statement is as follows:

$\sqrt{n} \mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ converges simply almost everywhere to $0$.

I know that the indicator function on $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ converges to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ but why does the product converges to 0? How do you show it properly?

Comment: The convergence is a.e. only (for $x=0$ it doesn't hold). If $x>0$ and $\frac{1}{n}<x$, then $\sqrt n\boldsymbol 1_{[0,1/n]}(x)=0$.

Comment: I think the answer present at the location [Convergence almost surely by definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3507150/convergence-almost-surely-by-definition) answers your question, if you're talking about a.e. convergence. I could be wrong, of course, in that case let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x > 0$ then there exists $N \in \mathbf N$ with $\frac 1N < x$ and thus the property that $\sqrt{n} 1_{[0,\frac 1n]}(x) = 0$ for all $n \ge N$.

If $x = 0$ the sequence diverges to $\infty$.

If $x < 0$ the sequence is identically $0$.

Comment: Oh yes, this makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Pick any real number $x \ne 0$. For sufficiently large $n$, the number $x$ will lie outside of the interval $[0, 1/n]$, so $\sqrt{n} \mathbb{1}_{[0,1/n]}(x) = \sqrt{n} \cdot 0 = 0$ for all large $n$.